# How do you create vectors with different names in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I'm trying to create a bunch of vectors in c++, each having a different name. I've looked around on this site, and have not found any information that is 'simple', as I'm very new to c++. I would like to do it without importing libraries i've never used before.
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 2;
    int m = 4;
    double size = pow(m,n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
             vector<double> xi(size);
             // where xi would vary with the iteration through n
             // i.e. I would have vectors x1, x2 in the case of n=2
        }
return 0;
}
```

This isn't the simple case were I could create x1, and x2 by themselves at the start, because I won't know what 'n' will be, as it will be inputted by the user at the start of the program. What would be the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: simple answer: [not really](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/28821/)

Comment: Why can't you just use `x` every time? The scope of the variable is limited to the loop anyway, so you can reuse the name.

Comment: Variables only last as long as the scope they are declared in , so even if you did this it wouldn't be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use a vector of vectors.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> xArray;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
   vector<double> xi(size);

   // Fill up xi
   // ...

   xArray.push_back(xi);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're asking in C++. However, you can store your created vectors in another vector of vectors and thus, you can refer to them via their index in the vector of vectors that contains them:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> myvecs;
for(int i(0); i < n; ++i) {
  std::vector<double> xi(size);
  //...
  myvecs.push_back(xi);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to do it might make sense to use something like a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>`.

You could do this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> myMap;

for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
         vector<double> xi(size);
         string name;
         // Make a name with stringstream ... 
         myMap[name] = xi;
}
```

Then if need be you could search for the vector using `name, eg:

```
cout << "Name of your vector: "
cin << name;
cout << "Here is your vector"
std::vector<int> &myVect = myMap[name];
// Do some printing.
```