# Read .txt file and put each line into vectors

Tags: c++, string, class, vector

I am having a hard time figuring out how this will work

My instructions as follows: 
One line from the file (inputted as a string) goes into one vector of strings. So, if the file has 25 lines, you will end up (after input) with 25 vectors of string(s), each containing one string. Then you begin joining pairs of vectors into larger vectors until there is only one vector containing all of the strings.
My question is how would I read a file and create a vector for each line that it has since that number is always different?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a vector of vectors.  This way you can refer to each individual vector using an index.

[How do you create vectors with different names in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744596/how-do-you-create-vectors-with-different-names-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Since vectors are dynamic and don't need to have fixed sizes like arrays, you can simply create a vector of vectors to store all lines of the file into. If your file has 25 lines, then there will be a single vector that has 25 vectors of strings in it. Please see sample code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

/*
There is a file (sample.txt) created for this example that contains the following contents:

hello world
this is a long line of words
while
this
is
a
short
line
of
words

*/

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    ifstream file_To_Read(argv[1]);            //Creating an ifstream that opens a file from a command line argument

    vector< vector<string> > complete_Vector;  //This is a single vector that will contain multiple vectors

    string line;                               //String used to store file contents a line at a time
    vector<string> tempVec;                    //Vector that will contain the singular line
    while(getline(file_To_Read, line))         //While you can read the file's content a line at a time, place its content into line
    {
        tempVec.push_back(line);
        complete_Vector.push_back(tempVec);
    }

    //The sample file has 10 lines, so complete_Vector.size() should be 10 (10 vectors are in it)
      return 0;
}
```